# Apache2 VirtualHost not showing right directory

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4

I've set up my Ubuntu server VPS with a LAMP stack serving a WordPress MU multi-site and using Let's Encrypt SSL certificates.  I had it running on my main domain: zonk.be and was trying to now get sub-domains working, which serve other WordPress sites from the same code base.

Now all my sub and main domain are not giving any errors any more, but 'Index of /' to an empty directory. For instance: https://zonk.be/.

My .conf files all look more or less the same, like the following

```
<VirtualHost *:433>
    ServerName zonk.be
    ServerAlias www.zonk.be

    ServerAdmin webmaster@zonk.be
    DocumentRoot /var/www/zonk.be/DEFAULT
    <Directory /var/www/zonk.be/DEFAULT>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.zonk.be-0001/cert.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.zonk.be-0001/privkey.pem
    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.zonk.be-0001/chain.pem
</VirtualHost>
```

I'm at a loss as to why it isn't showing the WordPress site.

Comment: probably a misconfigured or missing htaccess file.

Comment: It's the same .htaccess that's always been there and worked before: http://pastebin.com/WPMWqJbD

Comment: Can you provide any logs? Check /var/log/access.log to see what particular localtion you hit.

Comment: Here is the output from `tail /var/log/apache2/access.log` just after I tried to go to zonk.be : http://pastebin.com/tLFCvEL2

Answer (score 0):

I found what was wrong: I had disabled the default site, enabling default and default SSL fixed it, doing `a2ensite 000-default-le-ssl.conf`and `a2ensite 000-default.conf`